# OpenGL glViewport() (resetting coordinates)

Tags: c++, opengl, coordinates, reset, viewport

I have a problem with glViewport. In my liitle programm i have two viewports. I can draw a form (with the motionfunc) in one of those viewports and in the other a line is automatically drawn.
So far so good..
When i try to draw something with mousefunc the viewport is in a total different place. And it is very difficult to find the new correct coordinates for that viewport.
Is there a possibility to reset the coordinates..
I cant use glLoadIdentity in mouse or motion because then nothing is displayed.

I hope you understand what i mean. It is a bit difficult to explain.

OK here a codesnippet....

```
void mouse (int button, int state, int mx, int my)
{
if (modus == 0 && button==GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state != GLUT_DOWN) 
{
    ...
}

else if (modus == 1 && button==GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN) 
{


    **glViewport(10,10 , sw_w1, sw_h1);** 
//the drawing is much higher than in the first viewport in motion. 
//But it should be the same viewport like the first in motion.
    glBegin()...glEnd()
            glFlush();
}   
}   
void motion(int mousex,int mousey)
{
GLdouble h=12;
GLdouble winkel=360/h;
Line liste[num];

liste[++last].x =(mousex)-((sw_w1+2*GAP)/2);
liste[last].y   =(mousey)-((sw_h1+2*GAP)/2);

if (modus==0 && gruppe == 0) {
    if (last>=1)
    {
        glViewport(10, 10, sw_w1, sw_h1); //works fine
        glColor3d(R, G, B);
        for(h+1;h>0;h--){
            glRotated(winkel, 0, 0, 1);
            glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
            for(int i=last-1;i<=last;i++){
                glVertex2i(liste[i].x,liste[i].y);
            }
            glEnd();
        }

        glLineWidth(linewidth+0.5);
        glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
        glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
        for(int i=last-1;i<=last;i++){
            glVertex2i(liste[i].x,liste[i].y);
        }
        glEnd();
        glViewport(1020,10 , sw_w2, sw_h2); //works fine
        glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
        glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
        for(int i=last-1;i<=last;i++){
            glVertex2i(liste[i].x,liste[i].y);
        }
        glEnd();
    }
    glFlush();

}
}
```

The second and third viewport works fine. The first one is the same as the second but the picture is displayed much higher.Why is that so?
And how could i change it so that i get the same viewport like the second one.
I hope you now understand what i mean.

Comment: Maybe you should post some code to clarify what you want to do, as your despriptions are not very, well, descriptive.

Comment: At the top you see my changes to my question..

Comment: You should check your modelview/projection matrices and see if they are what you expect them to be in each function.

Comment: Not related, but don't use glFlush, it's slooow and glut will do that for you anyway

Comment: @Macke You are absolutely right. My mistake.I really thouhgt the problem was related to glViewport.Thought wrong. Thanks!     @Calvin1602 Hm, when im not using it, i cant draw anything. What should i use instead?

Comment: @buddy `glutSwapBuffers` (together with double buffering, of course)! By the way, don't draw in your motion func, just call `glutPostRedisplay`, or something the like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your modelview/projection matrices and see if they are what you expect them to be in each function.

Also, as Christian's commented, it is not necessary, nor recommended, to draw in the motion func. Update your application state per the input and call glutPostRedisplay to signal that you want to redraw your window. That way, your application will have a cleaner design and it will be easier to make it behave consistently.

*(added my comment as answer since that was the problem, and added Christian's comment, since that is the proper solution. **Don't draw in motionfunc!**.)*

Comment: Why is it a problem to draw in motionfunc?  I dont understand what you mean with: "Update your application state per the input " Have you an example. Is it allowed to draw in mousefunc? When I am calling glutPostRedisplay in glutdisplayfunc nothing works anymore. So where can i draw instead.

Comment: @buddy: you should store/use the input from mousefunc in some other variable (like update where your ship is heading, if your writing a game), and call glutPostRedisplay() from motionfunc. Similar for keyboardfunc, menufunc, etc etc. Calling  glutpostredisplay will tell GLUT to call glutdisplayfunc as soon as all events are processed. (So all drawing goies into displayfunc). Following that pattern is the de facto way to do event/redraw, and avoids problems like the one you're having, especially if there are many mouse events and you're running at a low framerate.